# Response to give for partially successful post to Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

What is the best response to give, if a number of objects are sent to my web api controller, to be inserted into my database, where some may be successful, and some may fail?  A normal HTTP response I don't think will suffice - would it be better to find some way of returning a JSON string of what has been successful, and what has not?  If so, how would I do that?

My Post controller is shown below.

Thanks for any help,

Mark

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PostBooking(Booking[] bookings)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var booking in bookings)
            {
                // check if there are any bookings already with this HID and RID...
                var checkbooking = db.Bookings.Where(h => h.HID == booking.HID && h.RID == booking.RID).ToList();
                // If so, return a response of conflict
                if (checkbooking.Count != 0 || checkbooking.Any())
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
                }
                else
                {
                    // If not add the booking to the database and return a response of Created
                    db.Bookings.Add(booking);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            } 
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            // Model is not valid, so return BadRquest
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a JSON list containing the ids of the objects that failed to be inserted:

```
{
    "failedIds": [
        4,
        7,
        9
    ]
}
```

500 HTTP response status code also seems appropriate as the request didn't complete successfully.

You could even bring that a step further and provide an explanation why insertion failed for each particular id:

```
{
    "failed": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "reason": "database unavailable"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "reason": "network cable unplugged"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "reason": "a thief is currently running away with our server"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi - would I have to create a model, to add IDs/successful/unsuccessful to, to return?  Would that then need something different to HttpResponseMessage (first line of controller) to allow JSON and a HTTP response to be sent? (thank you)

Comment: Yes, you have to create a model. And then `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, modelOfFailedIds);`

Comment: Once again, you've helped a newbie with what's probably a basic query - thank you @Darin-Dimitrov - I'll mark as the answer as soon as SO allows.

Comment: I wouldn't go with 500.  500 implies a server error. There are scenarios where the server has no problem at all processing the request, but the business conditions dictate the booking shouldn't succeed.  500 will actually throw an exception in some client libraries.  If you're going for this approach, then a 200 is more correct.

Comment: Ah, yeah, of course, if business conditions dictate this then 500 is not appropriate. 500 should be used if there's an internal server error. Unfortunately the OP didn't explain his scenario in sufficient details and the kind of failures he is expecting.

Comment: Hi - I've created a model in the models folder with ID, and RespMessage (string) - but how would I create a reference to that, and add a "successful/Failed", and add to it for each record that was posted?  eg.  PostResponse newPostResponse = new PostResponse();  newPostResponse.ID = xxxx;  newPostResponse.RespMessage = "Failed";  newPostResponse.Add (add doesn't exist, in intellisense) - thank you.

Comment: You need to use a collection. You may take a look at the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) generic type.